# 2D array assigns input to all inner arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to get the method input to be stored and outputted like this:

```
Want [ ["email addresses"], ["phone numbers"], ["names"] ]    - >    [["bobsmith@example.com","sallyfield@example.com"],["555-555-5555","111-111-1111"],["Bob Smith","Sally Field"]]
```

This is my code:

```
    def hash_2_array contacts
    2       # Extract like info from each hash into arrays
    3       stringArr = Array.new(3,Array.new(2))   #=> [ [ nil,nil]  , [nil,nil]  , [nil,nil]  ]
    4       
    5       if contacts.empty?
    6           return nonsense = Array.new(3, Array.new)
    7       else
    8          n=0 #name counter
    9          e=0 #email counter
    10         p=0 #phone counter
    11          contacts.each do |key, value|
    12              stringArr[2][n] = key.to_s              #adds name to array
    13              n+=1
    14              value.each do |key2, value2|
    15                  if key2.to_s.eql?("email")
    16                      stringArr[0][e] = value2.to_s   #adds email address to array
    17                      e+=1
    18                  else
    19                      stringArr[1][p] = value2.to_s   #adds phone number to array
    20                      p+=1
    21                  end
    22              end
    23          end
    24      end
    25      return stringArr
    26  end
    27  
    28  
    29  hash_2_array({:"Bob Smith"=>{:email=>"bobsmith@example.com", :phone=>"555-555-5555"}, :"Sally Field"=>{:email=>"sallyfield@example.com", :phone=>"111-111-1111"}})
```

It returns:

```
   got: [["555-555-5555", "111-111-1111"], ["555-555-5555", "111-111-1111"], ["555-555-5555", "111-111-1111"]]
```

It's really confusing why it's not just assigning only the the index in the array that I'm specifying. I think this code worked before, but now it's broken somehow. Any help would be great

Comment: Readers may want to run your code, with or without modifications. To do so, step 1 is to cut-and-paste. Step 2, which should not be necessary, is to remove all the line numbers. When presenting code please do not include line numbers, IRB prompts, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new):

> **new(size=0, default=nil)**
>   **new(array)**
>   **new(size) {|index| block }**
>   [...]
>   **Common gotchas**
>   When sending the second parameter, the same object will be used as the value for all the array elements:
>
> ```
> a = Array.new(2, Hash.new)
> # => [{}, {}]
>
> a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
> a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {"cat"=>"feline"}]
>
> a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
> a # => [{"cat"=>"Felix"}, {"cat"=>"Felix"}]
> ```
>
> If multiple copies are what you want, you should use the block version which uses the result of that block each time an element of the array needs to be initialized:
>
> ```
> a = Array.new(2) { Hash.new }
> a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
> a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {}]
> ```

When you say this:

```
stringArr = Array.new(3,Array.new(2))
```

You're creating an array with three elements but all those elements are exactly the same array. You want an array that contains three different arrays as elements:

```
stringArr = Array.new(3) { Array.new(2) }
```